# Facing java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/facebook/fb303/FacebookService$Iface error while starting hive

Tags: java, facebook, hadoop, hive

I have started Hadoop and tried starting hive, this is the error I got. I have just started my learning in Hadoop and hive, kindly help..

```
hduser@Venkat:/usr/lib/hive/apache-hive-1.1.0-bin$ bin/hive
```

> Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/apache-hive-1.1.0-bin/lib/hive-common-1.1.0.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
>   SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
>   SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/apache-hive-1.1.0-bin/lib/hive-jdbc-1.1.0-standalone.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
>   SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/facebook/fb303/FacebookService$Iface : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:643)
>       at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:643)
>       at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.getClass(MetaStoreUtils.java:1451)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:71)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:2841)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:2860)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:453)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:671)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:615)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unsupported major.minor version 51.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0)

Comment: ----here are my java and javac versions
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_34"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.6) (6b34-1.13.6-1~deb7u1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)

---javac
hduser@Venkat:/usr/lib/hive/apache-hive-1.1.0-bin$ javac -version
javac 1.6.0_34

Answer (score 1):

Your Java version is too old.  You need at least Java 7 for this code to run.

You may want to consider uninstalling all Java installations on your computer, and then install just ONE.  The latest Java 8 is a good choice if available for your platform.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently experiencing the same problem..

Here, you have two errors..

First, multiple binding, second one, the incompatible blah blah (not yet identified)

In order to solve this:
Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.

SLF4J: Found binding in **[jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]**

SLF4J: Found binding in **[jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/apache-hive-1.1.0-bin/lib/hive-jdbc-1.1.0-standalone.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]**

Delete one of this two, and it will not show anymore.
According to my readings, very basic understanding, it just needs only to bind to only one.

So for the second, let's help each other :) im also currently new to HADOOP. but since im working as BI Dev, this is my next level. :)